# Dividing a list into subsets according to a numeric array in Python

Tags: python, string, list, set

I have a `list` with characters like so:

```
s = ['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'N', 'N']
```

And the following array:

```
t = [2, 4, 3]
```

I would like to divide the list according to the array, such that each subset `st[i]` has `len(t[i])`. Result for this example should be:

```
st = [['Y', 'U'], ['U', 'N', 'U', 'U'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
```

If array t was:

```
t = [5, 2, 2]
```

Then the result should be:

```
st = [['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U'], ['U', 'N'], ['N', 'N']]
```

Entries are s and t. I am trying by inserting two loops, one for list s and another one for array t. But it is not working. How can I implement this?

Comment: `{'U','N','U','U'}` is not a valid set.  Sets can't have duplicate members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by iteratively carving chunks out of a copy of `s`:

```py
i = 0
result = []
s_copy = s.copy()

while s_copy:
    result.append(s_copy[:t[i]])
    s_copy = s_copy[t[i]:]
    i += 1
```

Comment: @ChrSld you're welcome. Make sure to accept one of the posted answers. I suggest the current top-voted answer. FWIW, both solutions voted above mine right now are using a module from the standard library (meaning you don't need to install anything, only import a module that comes with Python).

Answer (score 6):

You can create an iterator from `s` and use `itertools.islice` to slice the iterator according to the sizes in `t`:

```
from itertools import islice

i = iter(s)
[list(islice(i, l)) for l in t]
```

This returns:

```
[['Y', 'U'], ['U', 'N', 'U', 'U'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Should be accepted :)

Comment: Very clean. A note to OP: this will produce empty sublists if `sum(t) > len(s)` and will not fully capture `s` if `sum(t) < len(s)`. A general function should probably assert that `sum(t) == len(s)`.

Comment: `[x for l in (t + [None]) if (x := list(islice(i, l)))]` would take care of both cases, btw :D

Comment: But that's approaching code-golf levels of "don't actually do that"

Answer (score 3):

For an input of `[2, 4, 3]`, the starting indices would be:

- 0
- 0 + 2 = 2
- 0 + 2 + 4 = 6

You can use [itertools.accumulate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to collect the starting indices.

Once the starting indices are known, we just need to pair them via [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with the count of items to be grouped per starting index, which already what the list `[2, 4, 3]` is. Thus:

- start 0 : count 2
- start 2 : count 4
- start 6 : count 3

Or as *@don'ttalkjustcode* mentioned in the comments, we can also track the accumulated stopping indices too:

- start (2 - 2 = 0) : stop 2
- start (6 - 4 = 2) : stop 6
- start (9 - 3 = 6) : stop 9

```
from itertools import accumulate

s = ['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'N', 'N']

for t in [
    [2, 4, 3],
    [5, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 6],
    [6, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
]:
    # Option 1: Using start/count logic
    z = [s[start:start+count] for start, count in zip(accumulate([0] + t), t)]

    # Option 2: Using stop/count logic (thanks to @don'ttalkjustcode for pointing this out!)
    # z = [s[stop-count:stop] for stop, count in zip(accumulate(t), t)]

    print(z)
```

**Output**

```
[['Y', 'U'], ['U', 'N', 'U', 'U'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
[['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U'], ['U', 'N'], ['N', 'N']]
[['Y'], ['U', 'U'], ['N', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'N', 'N']]
[['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U', 'U'], ['N'], ['N', 'N']]
[['Y', 'U'], ['U'], ['N', 'U', 'U', 'N'], ['N', 'N']]
[['Y', 'U'], ['U'], ['N', 'U'], ['U', 'N'], ['N'], ['N']]
```

Comment: Clever use of `accumulate`.

Comment: [stop version](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwEETv@Yq5qZAejK0Uob/QWw9FchCpNKBJiOuh/nxqYm09dFmWebNsmNgXPY0uztZ53zkzQNHDkTH9CDVY4whN207D1Df0YGzEBXVyTziS23dc/@BnSMY640BQGjXDUrXgOHIUkq944lgcsWEesdyw5Mh3WxFxf746IvYi8sWXVVzNIepYj2TsoTWTpipIiZAnKI7ohmSzsunvlyllHJTJ@Ip1SlM6Z96/AQ) looks even nicer to me, doesn't need adding [0] and uses the last sum. Also @blorgon

Comment: Yeh, but top answer definitely is the most elegant. It's basically the functional version of my answer, using `iter(s)` instead of a `while` loop. Consuming an iterable, at least in my opinion, is the most intuitive solution.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that seems a cleaner approach for this solution :) I updated the answer to include that perspective of doing the accumulation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are intending to achieve is not possible using set inside a list, since set doesn't allow duplicate items; however, you can use 2D List:

```py
s = ['Y' 'U' 'U' 'N' 'U' 'U' 'N' 'N' 'N']
t = [2, 4, 3]
t = [0] + t
result = []
for f,l in zip(t, t[1:]):
    result.append(s[f:l].split(''))
```

Comment: @blorgon, I was updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use:

```
s = ['Y', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'N', 'N']
t = [2, 4, 3]
st = []
offset = 0
for size in t:
    st.append(s[offset:size+offset])
    offset += size

print(st)
```

Comment: The question was initially about making a list of sets. My answer was catering to that. I did not notice the question changed later on and my answer is not fitting anymore. Have adjusted it now.